# Squid cache log gives "Page faults with physical" errors! Is it a memory issue?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have setup a Squid proxy on a small machine which have 640MB of ram. I have also disabled the cache with "cache deny all"

When I checked the cahce log... I see an error like this :

> CPU Usage: 0.248 seconds = 0.140 user + 0.108 sys
>
> Maximum Resident Size: 51232 KB
>
> Page faults with physical i/o: 0
>
> Memory usage for squid via mallinfo():
>
> ```
>    total space in arena:    2112 KB
>
>    Ordinary blocks:         2107 KB     19 blks
>
>    Small blocks:               0 KB      1 blks
>
>    Holding blocks:         26652 KB      9 blks
>
>    Free Small blocks:          0 KB
>
>    Free Ordinary blocks:       4 KB
>
>    Total in use:           28759 KB 1362%
>
>    Total free:                 4 KB 0%
> ```

Can some one please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error. You can read some explanation from [here](http://www.comfsm.fm/computing/squid/FAQ-9.html#ss9.24).